# Android : intent putExtra causing error

Tags: android, android-intent

I have 2 activities transferring a String variable from on to the other with a putExtra intent. I am using two buttons in the onclick method of the sender activity, one button retrieves a word from an array in another class and sends it to the recieving activity. The other button sends the String from an editText field. However, i am getting an error, any help appreciated.

Sending class

```
public class TitleScreen extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

Button onePlayer, twoPlayer, play;
EditText inputWord;
String b;


WordDifficulties wordDiff = new WordDifficulties();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_title_screen);

    onePlayer = (Button) findViewById(R.id.OnePlayer);
    twoPlayer = (Button) findViewById(R.id.TwoPlayer);
    play = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Continue);

    inputWord = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.enterWord);
    inputWord.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    play.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    onePlayer.setOnClickListener(this);
    twoPlayer.setOnClickListener(this);
    play.setOnClickListener(this);

}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    if (v.getId() == R.id.OnePlayer) {

        Intent myIntent = new Intent(TitleScreen.this, MainActivity.class);
        myIntent.putExtra("gameWord", wordDiff.getRandomWord());
        startActivity(myIntent);
        finish();

    } else if (v.getId() == R.id.TwoPlayer) {
        onePlayer.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        twoPlayer.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        inputWord.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        play.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    } else if (v.getId() == R.id.Continue){

        // if no word is inputed then game will not start 
        if(inputWord.getText().toString().trim().length() == 0){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Enter a word",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else{
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(TitleScreen.this, MainActivity.class);
            myIntent.putExtra("gameWord", inputWord.getText().toString());
            startActivity(myIntent);
            finish();
        }
    }
  }
}
```

receiving activity within the onCreate method

```
    Intent myIntent = getIntent();
    secretWord = myIntent.getStringExtra("gameWord");
```

here is the logCat

```
Shutting down VM
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.hunglikeanandroid, PID: 3431
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.hunglikeanandroid/com.example.hunglikeanandroid.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.lang.String.length()' on a null object reference
atandroid.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2209)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.lang.String.length()' on a null object reference
at com.example.hunglikeanandroid.MainActivity.<init>(MainActivity.java:35)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1572)
at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1065)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2199)
```

Comment: have you initialized inputWord

Comment: `.MainActivity.<init>(MainActivity.java:35)`

Comment: this happens only in TwoPlayer click ?

Comment: yes input word only happens in TwoPlayer Click, OnePlayer click still crashes

Comment: Remove    ` finish();`

Comment: removing finish() does nothing

Comment: I've edited the full sending class code

Comment: Check your MainActivity or post line 35 because that class is creating the error.

Comment: Next time, try reading the error. It points out exactly the line with which there is a problem.

Answer (score 0):

were have you registered your edittext

```
inputWord=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.inputWord);
```

Because the error says  `NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.lang.String.length()' on a null object reference`

Answer (score 0):

Change code `if(inputWord.getText().toString().trim().length() == 0)` to `if(inputWord.toString().equals(""))`

Comment: I have already defined inputWord, I attached the full code above